Google advertise my site as "For Sale" in search result's page titles
site:legacy2.net
First result for me is: "Privacy Policy - Legacy2.net is for sale"
While the page title is "Legacy2 - Privacy Policy"
I have a clue that years ago this domain was actually for sale (I looked it up via web.archive.org), but still weird because Google only indexed the site yesterday, before it was not in Google.
Anyone have any idea how to fix this issue?
I used Google search console to index my site and while Google indexed it, some page title says my site is for sale.

Google don't index every page that they crawl, but they are going to still keep any data which they have discovered about a domain in their database.
My assumption is that at some point Google have either followed a link from a domain squatter, or discovered a newer holding page than Internet Archive have found.  This will have signalled to Google that the name of your site is "Legacy2.net is for sale", as that will have been the only thing they have to go on.
I'd assume this suffix will vanish when the site is fully indexed and better signals tell it that this is not the name of the site.  The fact they haven't indexed your homepage yet would be a bigger SEO issue based on the site: search, but I assume that's also just about giving Google time to fully crawl, clear their caches and re-index.
Give it a couple of weeks before deciding if it is actually a problem. I doubt it will be.
